# Only summing date deltas for date ranges not already accounted for

Tags: sqlite, date

These are the tables that I'm working with.

```
CREATE TABLE status ('rowid' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    statusId INTEGER,
    userId INTEGER,
    invocation DATETIME,
    expiration DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(userId)
    FOREIGN KEY(statusId) REFERENCES status_available(statusId)
);

INSERT INTO "status" ("rowid","statusId","userId","invocation","expiration") VALUES ('2','7','1','2016-05-01','2016-07-10');
INSERT INTO "status" ("rowid","statusId","userId","invocation","expiration") VALUES ('720','7','1','2016-09-22','2016-12-31');
INSERT INTO "status" ("rowid","statusId","userId","invocation","expiration") VALUES ('727','7','1','2017-01-01','2017-01-31');
INSERT INTO "status" ("rowid","statusId","userId","invocation","expiration") VALUES ('973','7','1','2017-08-12',NULL);
INSERT INTO "status" ("rowid","statusId","userId","invocation","expiration") VALUES ('976','1','1','2006-06-05',NULL);

CREATE TABLE status_available (
    statusId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    statusName TEXT NOT NULL,
    statusOrder INTEGER,
    statusClass TEXT,
    statusAccrueTime BOOLEAN
);

INSERT INTO "status_available" ("statusId","statusName","statusOrder","statusClass","statusAccrueTime") VALUES ('1','Active',NULL,'active','1');
INSERT INTO "status_available" ("statusId","statusName","statusOrder","statusClass","statusAccrueTime") VALUES ('5','Deceased',NULL,'dead','0');
INSERT INTO "status_available" ("statusId","statusName","statusOrder","statusClass","statusAccrueTime") VALUES ('7','Employee',NULL,'employee','1');
INSERT INTO "status_available" ("statusId","statusName","statusOrder","statusClass","statusAccrueTime") VALUES ('9','Inactive',NULL,'inactive','0');
INSERT INTO "status_available" ("statusId","statusName","statusOrder","statusClass","statusAccrueTime") VALUES ('16','Terminated',NULL,'term','0');

CREATE TABLE profile (
    'userId' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,'nameFamily' TEXT,'nameGiven' TEXT,'picture' TEXT,'dateJoined' DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 'dateOfBirth' DATETIME, 'numberBadge' INTEGER, 'accessLevel' INTEGER, 'bio' BLOB, 'theme' TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(userId)
);

INSERT INTO "profile" ("userId","nameFamily","nameGiven","picture","dateJoined","dateOfBirth","numberSocial","numberBadge","accessLevel","bio","theme") VALUES ('1','John','Doe','6b71b487774b3f881a52073774560e39c60cab52.png','2006-06-05','1988-12-16','29','255',NULL,'night');
```

The `status` table is natural joined onto `status_available` to produce the full row information. Currently to get someone's length of service, I do the following query.

`SELECT SUM((IFNULL(expiration, date()) - invocation)) AS LenOfSrv FROM status NATURAL JOIN status_available WHERE userId = ? AND statusAccrueTime = 1 GROUP BY userId;`

---

The problem that I'm having is that, all dates are SUMed. This is regardless of if their date ranges, computed by (`expiration` OR `date()`) - `invocation`, are already accounted for in another row. So my question is, how do I remove date ranges that are already accounted for in another row from the SUM?

Comment: Please show sample data to make your question more clear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Done! Sorry it wasn't clear. Probably the reason I'm having so much trouble is that I can't even rubber ducky this problem out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want to accomplish. Also your query is strange: if you only have one UserId, you don't have to group by it.
If what you say is that you retrieve several records but with the same Length of service information, then the answer is simple: use distinct.

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT (IFNULL(expiration, date()) - invocation)) AS LenOfSrv 
FROM status 
NATURAL JOIN status_available
WHERE userId = ? 
AND statusAccrueTime = 1
```

Comment: I did include sample data in the post above, with an edit.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "accounted for"?

Comment: I mean that when the `invocation` & `expiration` is already in another row, it shouldn't sum these values. For example if I'm "Active" from `2006-06-05` and currently still active (By the value of `NULL`). The fact that I'm an shown as an "Employee" from `2017-01-01` - `2017-01-31` shouldn't count towards my length of service in the SUM. Likewise if I had a status before `2006-06-05` it should only SUM up to `2006-06-05`. I'm basically trying to find all of the continuous times and sum them together.